# Is there any technical reason why throughput would significantly differ between an Java application and a C++ application?

Tags: java, c++, networking, network-programming

Given two applications, one written in Java and the second written in C++, is there any reason why they would have different network throughput? Both applications are fairly simple and identical in terms of functionality - they simply open a socket (let's say a UDP socket, for the sake of argument) and start writing the same data through.

It's safe to assume that both applications are running under the same conditions - same hardware, same operating system at both endpoints, same network, same configuration settings, and so forth. It's really as identical as you can possibly make it. It's also safe to assume that both have undergone similar optimization.

I can't think of a reason, but I might be overlooking something, perhaps in the way the JVM handles data traffic over networks or interacts with the operating system.

At this point, this question is mostly hypothetical. The applications don't exist - I'm just trying to determine if there's any performance-based reasons to consider one environment over the other.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is in how the underlying implementations are done.  Perhaps the lower-level code may be more or less robust.  A good check would be to create a simple one-way communication program for both and perform a saturation test.

Comment: Not writing this as an answer because the question is specifically about throughput... Although there have been efforts in building realtime Java, they appear to be lagging far behind the vanilla Java VMs. So while *throughput* may be comparable, I know of industries where predictable latency drives developers to stick with C++.

Comment: @D.N. By underlying implementations, do you mean the native, OS-specific implementations used by the JVM? I would like to think that those are pretty well optimized and reliable. If you could provide some resources on saturation testing and post this as an answer, that would be great.

Comment: @Thomas Owens Yes, I was referring to the OS-specific implementations.  Obviously C++ code would be compiled to the environment, but something tells me the JVMs may not be as highly optimized.  I don't have any specific saturation resources - I was just hypothesizing.  I assume all you would need to do is set up some UDP (or TCP, depending on what you want to test) traffic and monitor the throughput through a monitoring program like Wireshark.  If you think that's a sufficient answer, I'll write it up.

Answer (score 4):

Most software won't be running on such a fast network (relative to CPU speed) that it will matter.  If you want to service thousands of clients simultaneously, you might see a small difference (assuming both implementations have appropriate amounts of tuning work done).

Comment: Just to make sure I'm reading right: If (network speed >> CPU speed) or (clients --> large number), then it might make a significant difference. Otherwise, probably not.

Comment: I'm just curious. How do you compare network speed (bits/second) to CPU speed (Hz)? Is there some equation or guidance to equate them?

Comment: For example, a gigabit network using an embedded processor around 400 MHz, or a 10 gigabit network with an Intel Atom.  That's the kind of disparity that would make me start digging.